# Asus x551M shut down and won't come on

Tags: asus-laptop

My ASUS X551M shut down itself and won't come on. It does not even take power when I plug in the charger. My friend has exact model and I tried their charger so I know it is not the charger.
Can you please help me because it's a new laptop without a warranty. 
I tried the suggestion about taking internal battery out. Held power button down for 75 seconds and put battery back in...the battery seems to be dead too so I plugged it in and still no indicator light :(

Comment: What was the last thing you did before shutdown? Any bumps, odd actions, etc?

Comment: How can you buy a new laptop without a warranty?

Comment: Dooley_labs, I had just driven to my nieces wedding. It was secured in its case in the trunk padded by pillows. When I arrived and tried turning it on it would not come on. It was a 4 hr trip.

Comment: DavidPostill, because not everyone has the extra money to pay for warranty.

Comment: A "new" laptop will have a manufacturer warranty - usually 12 months - for precisely these types of events where a component or total failure occurs. As Ryan Babchishin's answer suggests it may be the charging socket or the charging circuit that is faulty or damaged. If it is damaged because you didn't disconnect the charger from the laptop during transit then you will have to foot the repair bill.

Answer (score 0):

1st, try your friends battery when it's fully charged. It could be your laptop is not charging it's battery or getting any power at all.

Otherwise...

Easy things to fix that might cause this problem are the power button and the DC power jack. If you want to take it apart, they are not so hard to replace or expensive (usually). Check ebay for the parts.

I know it sucks, but unless you can find a non-surgical way to deal with it, you might be stuck part swapping.

http://www.ebay.ca/itm/ORIGINAL-DC-POWER-JACK-ASUS-X551M-X551MA-X551MAV-X551CA-CONNECTOR-PORT-SOCKET-/321793708307?hash=item4aec665113

http://www.ebay.ca/itm/60NB0480-PS1040-200-GENUINE-ASUS-POWER-BUTTON-BOARD-WITHOUT-CABLE-X551M-A-/291432961224?hash=item43dac214c8

Comment: Thanks I did have to take it apart to remove the internal battery and I did check for appearance of damages but nothing seemed loose or disconnected. I will look into a replacement part for the DC power jack as I am thinking thats all it could be. My friend doesn't want their laptop opened to test battery. But any laptop I have worked with in the past will work plugged in without a battery and this still does not indicate power getting to the laptop. Thinking it has got to be the dc power jack...