# Asus X551M no power at all

Tags: laptop, motherboard, power-supply, power, asus-laptop

My issue is the same as the one here: [Asus x551M shut down and won't come on](https://superuser.com/questions/983202/asus-x551m-shut-down-and-wont-come-on), but this has not been resolved.

I have tried:

1. Removing the li-ion battery,
2. Removing the CMOS (which was completely dead),
3. Holding power button for more than 20 seconds.
4. Put new CMOS battery in,
5. Replaced li-ion battert,
6. Plugged in power.

There is voltage to the pins on the main board but no power lights and nothing happens when the power button is pressed.

The only thing I can think of is the power section of the main board has died.

Is there an option that isn't [ASUS X551MAV-EB01-B(S) Motherboard Intel Celeron N2830 60NB0480-MB2700-200](http://www.ebay.com/itm/ASUS-X551MAV-EB01-B-S-Motherboard-Intel-Celeron-N2830-60NB0480-MB2700-200-/151894556909?hash=item235d9f00ed:g:sdIAAOSw7FRWVMgK)  ?

Comment: Can this laptop run without a batttery?

Answer (score 0):

Common reasons for a laptop to not power on at all would include:

- Failed battery (only without AC power supply)
- Failed AC power supply
- Failed motherboard component
- Damaged power socket
- Residual charge

You have eliminated residual charge being an issue by removing all power sources and holding the power button. Assuming your statement of

> voltage to pins on main board

means you have tested the power from the AC adapter to the mainboard itself with a multimeter, you have likely eliminated the AC power supply and the damaged power socket from being an issue, and a failed battery is irrelevant if you've tested the machine without the battery, using just AC power.

It is still possible the AC adapter could be at fault even after testing power is getting to the mainboard, depending on what voltage is getting through (even then, some power supplies have a switching voltage making it hard to test whether it's actually faulty or not).

At this stage, the likely cause is due to a critical component failure on the motherboard. You can try some basics such as reseating any component or peripheral which can be reseated easily, such as RAM/HDD/DVD drive, although I wouldn't usually associate problems with these to the laptop not powering on at all.

Comment: i did a little probing with my multimeter at a few spots on the board. a few spots throughout the board i can get 19.1 volts, at the positive battery section with and without the battery i get ~2.7v.
i think that pretty much narrows it down to either the battery is bad and the laptop absolutely requires it to do anything. or the mainboard is bad.

Comment: So, is the battery required to run the laptop?